# External wpdb connections in different plugins on single page

Tags: plugins, database, mysql

I am writing plugins that connects to an external database, connecting to the external database using the wpdb class:

```
$mydb = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');
$rows = $mydb->get_results("select Name from my_table");
```

I want to have multiple plugins on a single page, all connecting to the same external database, but different tables.

If I try to have multiple plugins on a page, the first one works, but the ones underneath draw an error:

```
fatal error call to a member function get_results() on null
```

I tried to flush the connection to no avail. Besides creating a new `$mydb` for each plugin, is there a way to utilize the one class, but across different plugins? I've also tried `global $mydb` in the plugins underneath the first one but does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: Not all databases support external connections, are you sure this one does?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make the variable global when you define it, e.g.

```
global $mydb;
$mydb = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');
```

and then use `global $mydb;` in the other plugins. Aside from theme files, functions.php, and plugins while being loaded, pretty much nothing in WP runs in global context, so if you need to access global variables, you'll have to use `global`.